# grunt-nodemon didn't use nodemon to start server

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I use `express-generator` create the project skeleton, and use `jade`, `sass` instead of `ejs` and `stylus`, then i use `concurrent` to combine the `watch` and `nodemon` like [the doc](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon#advanced-usage), but when i run grunt tasks, output is:

---

[nodemon] v1.0.17
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: fir/***/*
[nodemon] starting `node bin/www`
Express server listening on port 3000
mongodb connection open

---

it's already use `node` to start server, How is it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Grunt, nodemon and Express allways are already to use NodeJS.

Nodemon, make easy cause you don't need allways, stop and start node to run your applications. If it don't work you can force reload using `rs`.